# Autofill Textbox using buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a `php` application that I'm working on. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a `search box` (`textbox`) and several `buttons`. On clicking each `button`, I want it to fill the `search box` with a predefined string. Clicking another `button` will erase what's in the `search box` and replace its value with its pre-defined string. And a button to clear the textbox as well.

Example:

```
Button 1
on click -> textbox value = button1 

Button 2 
on click -> textbox value = button2 (old value is replaced)
```

Can anyone guide me with the JS code that does this? Thanks!

Comment: show your tried code. this is very simple. just try once

Comment: When you say "guide me with the JS code..." do you mean "provide me with the JS code"?

Comment: I think I just answered my own questions after trying some! Will post the answer here.

Comment: @Rasclatt why does everyone just assume that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
function setText(obj) {
var val = obj.value;
document.getElementById('textBox').value = val;
}
</script>

<input type="button" name="btn1" id="btn1" value="Hello" onclick="setText(this)">

<input type="button" name="btn1" id="btn1" value="World" onclick="setText(this)">

<input type="button" name="btn1" id="btn1" value="StackOverflow" onclick="setText(this)">

<input type="text" name="textBox" id="textBox" value=""/>
```

Tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/o5fp0uq1/

Answer (score 1):

Apply 'button' class to every button and unique id for each button.

```
$(".button").click(function(){
     var id = this.id;
     $('#searchTextId').val($('#'+id).attr('value'));
});
```

Comment: this is not correct. you should not answer. user will not try if u provide ready made code.

Comment: Thanks. I just posted my code (answer) as well. Its a little different though using getElementById.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on('click','.click_me',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var search_val = $(this).attr('data-value');
  $('.text_search').val(search_val);
 });
 $(document).on('click','.clear_me',function(e){
  $('.text_search').val('');
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="click_me" data-value="text 1" value="button 1"/>
<input type="button" class="click_me" data-value="text 2" value="button 2"/>
<input type="button" class="click_me" data-value="text 3" value="button 3"/>
<input type="button" class="click_me" data-value="text 4" value="button 4"/>

<input type="button" class="clear_me" value="Clear"/>

<input type="text" class="text_search" />
```

Comment: Although I have answered my own question. I like this one better. Thank you!